# Segfault when opening Pantheon-files on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ubuntu, segmentation-fault, pantheon

I've been happily using pantheon-files on Ubuntu for a few years because having come from Mac-OS I simply cannot imagine working without Miller Columns. Suddenly today after having to kill an unresponsive program pantheon files has started crashing with a segfault every time I open it.

I have tried restarting, updating all software, even fully uninstalling pantheon, purging all settings, updating, and then reinstalling. Nothing works. I've gotten the default file explorer working just fine and have used it to delete all temporary files created by the killed program before the issue occurred but that also seems to have done nothing.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 and have updated pantheon to it's latest version with a fresh install.
The specific output from terminal right before it crashes (running with gdb):

```
(io.elementary.files:25510): GLib-CRITICAL **: 23:04:01.022: Source ID 112 was not found when attempting to remove it

(io.elementary.files:25510): Handy-CRITICAL **: 23:04:01.022: hdy_tab_view_close_page: assertion 'page_belongs_to_this_view (self, page)' failed

(io.elementary.files:25510): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 23:04:01.022: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(io.elementary.files:25510): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 23:04:01.022: g_signal_handlers_disconnect_matched: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

Thread 1 "io.elementary.f" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7f19f2c in files_abstract_slot_get_current_slot () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpantheon-files-core.so.6
```

If anyone has any idea how to fix this or what might be happening I would greatly appreciate any help. I am aware that the best workaround now is to use a different file program (which I'm doing for now), but I'm really not interested in any long-term solution that doesn't have Miller Columns.